# MSBuild Task CreateItem with files that exist

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-target

In a `msbuild` target, I am trying to create an item and it should include a list of files, only if they exist.

```
<CreateItem Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(OutputName).*.xyz" Condition="'$(IntermediateXyzFiles)' == ''">
    <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="IntermediateXyzFiles"/>
</CreateItem>
```

All the variables shown are defined.
Does anyone know how to add a condition for the file existence?

```
<CreateItem Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(OutputName).*.xyz" Condition="'$(IntermediateXyzFiles)' == '' and Exists('%(FullPath)')">
```

I tried the one above and it doesn't work for me.
Or is there another way to do this?